# Loop through an object of functions & add a single, new method to each single function within the Object

Tags: javascript, function, loops, object, proxy

I have an `object` of `functions` & I need to add a new, single `method` called `log`(it prints the `method`'s name) to each `function` within the `Object` dynamically at runtime.

For instance, let's say this is my dynamic `object` of `functions`:

```
let actions = { 
  theBoringFunction() { 
    return 'function 1'
  },

  anotherBoringFunction() {
    return 'function 2'
  },

  theMostBoringFunction() {
    return 'function 3'
  },
}
```

I can add a new `function` to the methods individually like so:

```
actions.anotherBoringFunction.log = function () {  
  return console.log(this.name)
}

actions.anotherBoringFunction.log() // logs anotherBoringFunction
```

It works like a charm, but I have many `functions` within the `actions object` & I need to add `log()` to all of them.

I have tried looping through the `object` & adding the `method` like so:

```
// won't work key is typeof String :(
for (let key in actions) { 
  key.log = function () { 
    return console.log(this.name)
  }
}
```

Obviously, it didn't work cause `key` is a type of `string` so it cannot add a `method` to it. How could I accomplish what I'm looking for? I have been trying with [proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), but no luck so far either.

**Edit Number 1:**

I have added a reproducible, example **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/4en3wux7/)**.

```js
let actions = { 
  theBoringFunction() { 
    return 'function 1'
  },

  anotherBoringFunction() {
    return 'function 2'
  },

  theMostBoringFunction() {
    return 'function 3'
  },
}

// won't work key is typeof String :(
/* for (let key in actions) { 
  key.log = function () { 
    return console.log(this.name)
  }
} */

actions.anotherBoringFunction.log = function () {  
  return console.log(this.name)
}

actions.anotherBoringFunction.log() // logs anotherBoringFunction
```

Comment: `actions[key].log =`, `key` is the property name (a string)

Comment: `for..in` loops through the keys - you want `for..of` for the values.

Comment: @RobinZigmond `for ... of` works on iterables, you'd have to use e.g. `for (let fn of Object.values(actions)) fn.log = /*...*/`, which indeed would also work.

Comment: I am not fully sure i understand your intend. You could create some abomination that behaves similarly in your case, but generally, [arrow functions and regular functions are not freely exchangeable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-exchangeable). If a regular function's behavior of `this` (which you do seem to use) is your intention, then changing to an arrow function may be counter-productive. If you mean doing the assignments, then `Object.values(actions).forEach(v => v.log = /*...*/);`, but I'd prefer abovementioned `for ... of` then

Comment: It kind of depends on your intentions - what you are currently doing, is creating a new `log` function for every property, while the function itself uses `this` to log the related name. Therefore, you could use the same `log` function for all of them (just one function), but i don't know, what this code's intention and use-cases are.

Comment: @ASDFGerte thanks, you are of course correct, I always seem to forget this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (let key in actions) { 
  actions[key].log = function () { 
    return console.log(this.name)
  }
}
```